# Javascript: Add full cookie to request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies

I am attempting to use javascript to set a cookie with an expiration date. Using Chrome, I can see that it creates it properly using the code below:

```
document.cookie = "IsAuthd" + '=' + "SomeVal" + ';expires=Sat, 08 March 2014 00:00:01 GMT';
```

However, when I execute an AJAX call directly after this (using jquery), the cookie is only half-passed in the request headers. In the request, I see:

Cookie: IsAuthd=SomeVal

But not the expiration. Can anyone explain why this is and why I can't send this WHOLE cookie over?

Here is the ajax code I use:

```
  $.ajax({
            type: 'GET', 
            url: '/Test/CollectCookie', 
            data: { }, 
            cache: false, 
            success: function () {
                console.log("done with ajax call");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how cookies work. The expiry is only for the benefit of the browser. Passing it back and forth is needless overhead.

Comment: Yep, beat me too it.. Sever can set the expire time when sending a page to a client, or the client can set it with javascript (as OP described). However, it's up to the client to actually expire the cookie. Wikipedia has a nice write up too:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age